# Map literal must contain an even number of forms

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to make an requiest to a web service which requires data in json and a secret (:key)

```
(ns fdsfdsfds.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as client])
  (:require [clojure.data.json :as json]))


(defn -main [& args]
  (client/post "https://fsdfdsfd.com/api/fdsfds" 
    {:body {(json/write-str {:key "fdsfdsfdsfd"})}}))
```

I'm having an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Map literal must contain an even number of forms
```

There're the even number of them, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 {:body {    (json/write-str {:key "fdsfdsfdsfd"})     }}
             ^-- single item       missing value? --^
        ^----- this is a map too
```

There's nothing paired with the function call.

The `:body` has a map as a value, but you only have a function in there, not a possible key for its value, or if that is the key, there's no value for it.

You probably want to remove the outer map brackets and leave:

```
{:body (json/write-str {:key "fdsfdsfdsfd"})}
```

EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:

You're asking why the [example on the site](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) is using a map. Look carefully at the value being used, it's a string

```
(client/post "url://site.com/api"
  {:basic-auth ["user" "pass"]
   :body "{\"json\": \"input\"}"
   ;; ...
```

The map is made up of lines of key/value pairs. The first is

```
key = :basic-auth, value = ["user" "pass"]
```

The value here is an array.

The second line is:

```
key = :body, value = "any old string"
```

In this case the string is an escaped map, the same that would be returned from calling `json/write-str`

Comment: i've update my answer. If your want a value in the body element of the map, you don't need the brackets surrounding the call to `json/write-str`

Comment: why isn't the outer "{" and "}" needed? in here https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http it is needed

Comment: because in that example the author is `post`ing the string value `:body "{\"json\": \"input\"}"`. That's a string of a map, not a map. Notice the double quotes around the brackets to make it just a string.